# Python POST sql query result

Tags: python, arrays, json, post, urllib2

I want to send a bunch of results to a server.

```
cur.execute('SELECT a,b,c,b FROM wicap WHERE a.num > 600 limit 25')
r = cur.fetchall()
```

r at this time is:

```
[(1487590224, 1487614532, -75, -41, 504, -73),
(1487596562, 1487614915, -75, -59, 156, -75),...]
```

I want to do something like:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/post/', data=r)
```

And on the server side be able to get the data via:

```
def POST()
data = web.data()
for record in data...
```

and then process the query result in the server.

urlencode fails with *ValueError: too many values to unpack*
I've tried creating a json with res = [dict((cur.description[i][0], value) for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in r]
but f = urllib2.urlopen(_url,res) returns *TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list*

Ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the data to json with `json.dumps`:

```
import json


r = [(1487590224, 1487614532, -75, -41, 504, -73), (1487596562, 1487614915, -75, -59, 156, -75)]
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/post/', data=json.dumps(r))
```